# ¿Cómo mostrar un mapa de carto en ionic 2 o Angular 2?

Tags: ionic, angularjs-2.0, ionic2

¿Alguien sabe como mostrar un mapa de carto en inonic 2? Cuando usaba ionic 1 no tenía problema ya que es angularjs y podía incluir la librería de carto en el index.html:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css">
  <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
```

y después usarla en un controller.js así:

```
   var mapa; mapa = new L.Map('mapa', { center: [39,-6], zoom: 9 })

   cartodb.createLayer(mapa, layerUrl)
        .addTo(mapa)
        .on('done', function(layer) {});
```

Pero el problema es ahora estoy usando ionic 2, que es angular 2, typescript. Después de añadir las librerías igual que arriba, intento crear el mapa de la misma manera en un archivo .ts pero me indica error porque no puede encontrar ese nombre.

¿Alguien tiene idea de como puedo mostrar el mapa? ¿O como usar una librería js en typescript?

No sé si me he explicado muy bien, cualquier cosa preguntadme.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hay varias opciones. Lo más fácil teniendo lo que tienes es poner en tu archivo ts lo siguiente: `declare const L` Y así evitas errores de compilación de typescript. Útil si la librería q estas usando no la instalas con npm o cuando no tienen archivos de declaración `.d.ts`

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funcionó perfectamente!